# python sharepoint get term store

Tags: python, office365

I'm trying to create a small python program to get list content.
till there everything id working fine, except that..
Some column are lookups column comming from the term store so i want to get the term store value to join them in my get list result to have the lookup value instead of the term id

my code so far is with the Office365-REST-Python-Client==2.4.4 version

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
import pandas as pd
import sys

sharepoint_url = "https://my url/sites/mysite"
library_name = "MyDocumentLibrary"
auth_context = AuthenticationContext(sharepoint_url)
try:
    if auth_context.acquire_token_for_user(username, password):
        # Successfully acquired the token
        print("Successfully authenticated")
        # Create a SharePoint client context
        ctx = ClientContext(sharepoint_url, auth_context)
        library = ctx.web.lists.get_by_title(library_name)
        ctx.load(library)
        items = library.get_items()
        ctx.load(items)
        # Execute the query to fetch library and items metadata
        ctx.execute_query()
        # Create a list to store the data
        data = []

        # Extract and store item data in the list
        for item in items:
            data.append(item.properties)
    
        # Create a pandas DataFrame from the list
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)

        ######## Collect Term store to replace GUID with term value #######
        
    else:
        print("Failed to authenticate")
        sys.exit()
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Failed to connect: {str(e)}")
    sys.exit()
```

and from here i'm stucked, it's a corporate Office 365 environnement so i only have my username and password. i cannot acces to client secret or client id to create an API request. ideally i will use the ctx context client to get term store and his child. but documentation is not present for this case.

Thank you for helping